# How to add custom font in Jspdf with react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to add custom font in Jspdf with react? I tried every possible solution but nothing is working.I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

convert your font.ttf file to js file using a this site : https://peckconsulting.s3.amazonaws.com/fontconverter/fontconverter.html

then take the font name and type,
export the the callAddFont function and call it where you want .

```
//this in the js file we generated from 
//peckconsulting.s3.amazonaws
var font ".....
          .....
          .....";


var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS("Calibri Bold-normal.ttf", 
font);
this.addFont("Calibri Bold-normal.ttf","Calibri 
Bold", "normal");
};

 export { callAddFont };
 // your component
import { callAddFont } from "./fonts/Calibri 
Bold-normal";
 .....
 .....
  
 jsPDF.API.events.push(["addFonts", 
 callAddFont]);

 var doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", [220, 250]); 
 doc.setFont("Calibri Bold", "normal");
 doc.text("example")
```

Comment: I think, your answer could also answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603013/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-jspdf), but I fail to adapt. Could you please explain, how the files new-font.js (from the font converter), create-pdf.js (the file with `const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({...});`) and index.html have to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly working with fonts in jsPDF is a real pain in the back. In most cases I personally prefer to use [rasterizehtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rasterizehtml) or [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf) in complex with jsPDF. However, if you have no choice, I recommend watching this [example](https://codepen.io/stuehler/pen/pZMdKo)

```
function createPDF() {
  const doc = new jsPDF({
    unit: "pt",
    orientation: "p",
    lineHeight: 1.2
  });

  doc.addFont("Arimo-Regular.ttf", "Arimo", "normal");
  doc.addFont("Arimo-Bold.ttf", "Arimo", "bold");
  doc.setFont("Arimo");
  doc.setFontType("normal");
  doc.setFontSize(28);
  doc.text("Hello, World!", 100, 100);
  doc.setFontType("bold");
  doc.text("Hello, BOLD World!", 100, 150);
  doc.save("customFonts.pdf");
}
```

The code is clear but it's doesn't matter... Pay attention on Pen's Settings:

[image]

So the answer is using [jspdf-customfonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-customfonts) and its tool **makeFont**

`node makeFonts.js` - to create a new dist/default_vfs.js