# How can I use a custom font in jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

I know, this question has been asked e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908266/custom-font-faces-in-jspdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961572/add-custom-font-in-jspdf) but whatever I try, I do not get my custom font in the generated pdf. Here are my steps:

- Download ttf from [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro).
- As described in the [official readme](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8), convert ttf to js [here](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html).
- Add the js file to wwwroot folder.
- Add the following code in index.html `<body>`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="./SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.js" type="module"></script>
```

- Add create-pdf.js with following code to wwwroot folder:

```
export function generateAndDownloadPdf() {
    const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p',
        unit: 'pt',
        format: 'a4',
        putOnlyUsedFonts: true
    });
    doc.setFont("SourceSansPro-Regular", "normal");
    doc.text(50, 50, 'Hello world');
    doc.save("sample.pdf");
}
```

- In Index.razor add

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DownloadPdf">pdf</button>

@code {
    private async Task DownloadPdf()
    {
        await using var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./create-pdf.js");
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("generateAndDownloadPdf");
    }
}
```

- Run app, click button and observe that the font is not Source Sans Pro.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the custom font, follow the steps in the question and do the following:

##### index.html

Delete `type="module"`

```
<script src="./SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.js"></script>
```

##### SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.js

Modify to the following. (Do not forget to delete the line `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"`)

```
var font = 'AAE...';
var callAddFont = function () {
    this.addFileToVFS('SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.ttf', font);
    this.addFont('SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.ttf', 'SourceSansPro-Regular', 'normal');
};
jspdf.jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

##### Edit

If you want to add more than 1 custom font, modify the font js files as follows

```
(function () {
    var font = 'AAE...';
    var callAddFont = function () {
        this.addFileToVFS('SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.ttf', font);
        this.addFont('SourceSansPro-Regular-normal.ttf', 'SourceSansPro-Regular', 'normal');
    };
    jspdf.jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
})();
```

If you do not add the first and last line, the font will always be the last one, you added in index.html

Comment: Is that a typo or intended, the double `jspdf` references in line `jspdf.jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])` ?

Comment: It's not a typo. To be sure, I just created a new Blazor project, followed the steps in the question and did what I described in the answer. The pdf shows Source Sans Pro.